# Override writeStreamHeader method

Tags: java

I make a mini application in which an account is created, each account is an object that stores a login and password. I add it to the file, the problem is that it doesn’t need to be added to the file all at once, but one at a time when the button is pressed:

```
btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(tfLogin.getText().length()>=0 && tfPassword.getText().length()>=0 && tfPasswordTwo.getText().equals(tfPassword.getText())){
                AllGamers.saveAccaunt(new LoginAndPass(tfLogin.getText(), tfPassword.getText()));
```

Here is the code that writes objects to the file:

```
 public static void saveAccaunt(LoginAndPass gamers) {

    try {
        File file = new File("test");
        ObjectOutputStream os1 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        os1.writeObject(gamers);
        os1.close();
        ObjectOutputStream os2 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true)) {
            @Override
            protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
                reset();
            }
        };
        os2.writeObject(gamers);
        os2.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the code that reads them from the file:

```
 try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("test");
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            System.out.println(objectInputStream.readObject());
            System.out.println(objectInputStream.readObject());
            System.out.println(objectInputStream.readObject());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The problem is that when I read objects from a file, this is what it gives:

```
    Registratsiya.LoginAndPass@4dd8dc3
Registratsiya.LoginAndPass@6d03e736
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2960)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1540)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at Registratsiya.AllGamers.main(AllGamers.java:37)
```

Why does not read the third object, after all added them three, also happens with a large number, reads at most two.

The second day I can not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

With the first `writeObject(gamers)` call (`os1`) in `saveAccaunt()` you overwrite any existing `test` file. And with the second one (`os2`) you append the same object to the same file. So you basically end up having two times the same object in the `test` file. Now each time you call `saveAccaunt()` you overwrite the existing file.

With that said, after the second `objectInputStream.readObject()` you reached the end of that file, hence the `EOFException` at the third call.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand, but how to add this flag and where.

Comment: You already set it in the second call (`os2`) with the second argument (`true`) in `new FileOutputStream(file, true)` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileOutputStream.html)

Comment: Leave the code like this?  try {
            File file = new File("test");
            ObjectOutputStream os2 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true)) {
                @Override
                protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
                    reset();
                }
            };
            os2.writeObject(gamers);
            os2.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: Yes this should work. However, i'm not sure if storing login credentials this way is reasonable.

Comment: Now, when reading, it gives an error: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC

Comment: Yes os2.writeObject(gamers);
            os2.close();

Comment: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 79737200   There was such a mistake I lured

Comment: Is there e reason why you override the `protected void writeStreamHeader() `?

Comment: I do not understand what it means to cancel?

Comment: What do you mean by 'cancel'? I updated my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Objects are recorded normally, but when I read them out java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 79737200